# SQL query much slower on new server (5.7.19), vs old (5.5.52)

Tags: mysql

I'm moving my site from an old server to a newer one. As such, we are moving from mySQL **5.5.52** to **5.7.19**. However, there is a huge speed difference. I only happened to notice it as one of our scripts that normally takes 2 seconds to build a category, was taking 7 on the new one!

The new server is a Linode **12GB** RAM, 6 core server.

A test query:

> SELECT
>   glinks_Links.*,glinks_Category.linking,glinks_Category.LngNew,glinks_Category.Multilang_espanol_Name,glinks_Category.GoogleLat,glinks_Category.Town_Name,glinks_Category.HeaderFrench,glinks_Category.Category_Template,glinks_Category.GoogleMapZoom,glinks_Category.Multilang_english_Name,glinks_Category.Newest_Link,glinks_Category.CategoryFind,glinks_Category.newURLFormat,glinks_Category.FooterFrench,glinks_Category.Meta_Keywords,glinks_Category.Header,glinks_Category.Region_Cat_IDs_for_Map,glinks_Category.RelatedVilleLinks,glinks_Category.Meta_Description,glinks_Category.Footer,glinks_Category.isRegion,glinks_Category.Multilang_mobi_Name,glinks_Category.ShowMap,glinks_Category.Full_Name,glinks_Category.Direct_Links,glinks_Category.LatNew,glinks_Category.FatherID,glinks_Category.CatDepth,glinks_Category.Has_Changed_Links,glinks_Category.Name,glinks_Category.GoogleLong,glinks_Category.CatRoot,glinks_Category.Has_New_Links,glinks_Category.ClosestLinkIDs,glinks_Category.Payment_Mode,glinks_Category.Number_of_Links,glinks_Category.Multilang_onlinereservation_Name,glinks_Category.Payment_Description,glinks_Category.Template_Set_BAK,glinks_CatLinks.CategoryID
>   FROM glinks_CatLinks,glinks_Category,glinks_Links WHERE
>   glinks_CatLinks.LinkID = glinks_Links.ID AND
>   glinks_CatLinks.CategoryID = glinks_Category.ID AND
>   (glinks_CatLinks.LinkID = '139134')

Takes *0.0015* on the new server, and *0.0010* on the old one.

Something much simpler:

> SELECT * FROM glinks_Link_Images WHERE link_id_fk = 32934 ORDER BY
>   sort_order ASC

Takes *0.0006* on the new server, and *0.0004* on the new one. The new servers **my.cnf** file looks like:

```
[client]
port=3306
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]
user=mysql
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port=3306
basedir=/usr
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
tmpdir=/tmp
lc-messages-dir=/usr/share/mysql
log_error=/var/log/mysql/error.log

#sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
sql_mode=NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

symbolic-links=0

skip-external-locking
#key_buffer_size = 256M
tmp_table_size=256M
key_buffer_size=2G
max_allowed_packet = 64M
#table_open_cache = 256
max_heap_table_size=256M
table_open_cache=1024
sort_buffer_size = 1M
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 4M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size= 16M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=134217728

join_buffer_size=512k

#innodb_use_native_aio = 0
innodb_file_per_table

max_connections=500
max_user_connections=50
wait_timeout=500
interactive_timeout=500
long_query_time=5

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

...and the old one:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
local-infile=0
thread_cache_size=4
max_tmp_tables=32
query_cache_size=8M
max_delayed_threads=20
#table_open_cache=256
#skip-networking
query_cache_type=1
max_connections=500
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
open_files_limit=20558
sql-mode=""

# ones i've added
key_buffer_size=2G
tmp_table_size=256M
max_heap_table_size=256M
table_open_cache=1024
join_buffer_size=512k
interactive_timeout=500
wait_timeout=500
max_allowed_packet=1073741824
innodb_buffer_pool_size=134217728

#[mysqld]
#sql-mode=""
```

What am I missing? I would have thought it'd be a lot faster on a better spec machine, using a newer version of mySQL, so something must be up in our configuration - I'm just not too sure where to start!

**BTW:** The tables are in **MyISAM** format. I have tried it as **InnoDB**, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

**UPDATE:** Here is the output from a mysqltuner run:

```
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.7.4 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Logged in using credentials from debian maintenance account.
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Log file: /var/log/mysql/error.log(169K)
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log exists
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is readable.
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is not empty
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is smaller than 32 Mb
[!!] /var/log/mysql/error.log contains 18 warning(s).
[OK] /var/log/mysql/error.log doesn't contain any error.
[--] 0 start(s) detected in /var/log/mysql/error.log
[--] 0 shutdown(s) detected in /var/log/mysql/error.log

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 45M (Tables: 61)
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 8G (Tables: 206)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[!!] User 'admin_default@%' hasn't specific host restriction.
[!!] User 'chambres_links@%' hasn't specific host restriction.
[!!] There is no basic password file list!

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 2d 18h 24m 23s (36M q [153.362 qps], 5K conn, TX: 189G, RX: 6G)
[--] Reads / Writes: 94% / 6%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 11.7G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 2.7G
[--] Other process memory: 491.1M
[--] Total buffers: 2.4G global + 1.4M per thread (214 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 72B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 2.4G (20.55% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 2.7G (22.96% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/36M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 1% (3/214)
[!!] Aborted connections: 82.87%  (4722/5698)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[!!] Query cache may be disabled by default due to mutex contention.
[!!] Query cache efficiency: 0.0% (0 cached / 34M selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (1K temp sorts / 4M sorts)
[OK] No joins without indexes
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 14% (32K on disk / 223K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (3 created / 5K connections)
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 16% (342 open / 2K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 23% (240/1K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (41M immediate / 41M locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Memory used by P_S: 72B
[--] Sys schema is installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 21.9% (470M used / 2B cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 2.0G/1.6G
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (562M cached / 53K reads)
[!!] Write Key buffer hit rate: 71.3% (8M cached / 5M writes)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/45.9M
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (75 %): 48.0M * 2/128.0M should be equal 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk : 1 for 1 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.99% (2525768 hits/ 2526144 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 66.67% (2 hits/ 3 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 5 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is disabled.

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- RocksDB Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] RocksDB is disabled.

-------- Spider Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Spider is disabled.

-------- Connect Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Connect is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] This is a standalone server.

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Control warning line(s) into /var/log/mysql/error.log file
    Restrict Host for user@% to user@SpecificDNSorIp
    Reduce or eliminate unclosed connections and network issues
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
    Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64: 
    Beware that open_files_limit (1024) variable
    should be greater than table_open_cache (400)
    Read this before changing innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group: 
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_limit (> 1M, or use smaller result sets)
    table_open_cache (> 400)
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=16M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
```

**25/9/17**: As requested, here is the updated my.cnf file:

```
[client]
port=3306
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]
user=mysql
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port=3306
basedir=/usr
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
tmpdir=/tmp
lc-messages-dir=/usr/share/mysql
log_error=/var/log/mysql/error.log

#sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
sql_mode=NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

symbolic-links=0

skip-external-locking
#key_buffer_size = 256M
tmp_table_size=256M
key_buffer_size=2G
max_allowed_packet = 64M
#table_open_cache = 256
max_heap_table_size=256M
table_open_cache=1024
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size= 16M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=134217728

join_buffer_size=512k

#innodb_use_native_aio = 0
innodb_file_per_table

max_connections=500
max_user_connections=50
wait_timeout=500
interactive_timeout=500
long_query_time=5

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Answer (score 1):

Your additions of sort_buffer_size, read_buffer_size, read_rnd_buffer_size need to be REMOVED.  This will allow higher performance defaults to work for you.
Consider adding join_buffer_size = 512K which historically served you well.
Will look at more of your details and may have additional suggestions later.

Comment: thanks, I've made those changes. I've also just run mysqltuner and outputted the contents to the OP. Cheers :)

Comment: Is your performance better?

Comment: Is your performance any better?  
MySQLTuner results after 24 hours could be much more meaningful.  Some suggestions can be wrong.

Comment: kinda hard to tell, as its not a live server yet (only what I'm doing). I'm a bit confused as to what it means in the **Variables to adjust:** section.

Comment: does it matter the fact we have a 512MB swap disk? Would mysql have any advantage to having a 1 or 2GB swap?

Answer (score 0):

Variables to adjust:  are things to consider.  Search the manual for the name listed to see what role the variable plays.  Is your Build a Category better than 7 seconds now, even though you are not in 'production'?  Looking forward to a reposting of MySQLTuner results, even from pre-production.

Comment: Thanks Wilson. Unfortunatly it doesn't seem to have made a difference :( (both of my test queries also take the same time). I've had the server up for 72 hours now, and also have been running a "build", so some real world SQL was being run. I've updated my question above with the new output from sqltuner. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I did find this post: https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/06/03/binary-logs-make-mysql-5-7-slower-than-5-6/ . I tweaked my startup to: `su - mysql -s --sync_binlog=0 /bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/mysqld_safe > /dev/null 2>&1 &" ` It seems to have helped. Gotta be honest though, I'm not entirly sure what that does/did!

Comment: @Andrew  could you repost current my.cnf and put a date on it?
Also, do you know why ~80 % of connections were aborted?
Or is it just failure to 'disconnect' when client has completed their activities?
Do they have a logoff/logout option?

Comment: I'm not too sure why there are so many failed. I see this a lot in the error.log: `[Note] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)`. I tried to track down where its coming from, but can't. I guess its going to be a case of shutting down each bit of software, until it stops. For the updated values - I'll post those in a second

Comment: @andrewnewby  add/change to your .cnf/.ini
log_warnings=2
for additional information on failed connection attempts.
Your tolerance for hacker/cracker attempts is controllable with
max_connect_errors=nnnn   of times you will allow a cracker to attempt to
 gain access before 'rejection' see the refman.

Comment: thanks. So if I set `max_connect_errors=20`, it would let them try 10 times with wrong details, and then block them? Via iptables?

Comment: Please search your version of MySQL refman max_connect_errors to review your documentation.